# Chain rule for a transformation from $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Note that, for $z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C},$
$x=\frac{z+ \bar z}{2}\in \mathbb{R}~\hbox{and}~y=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}=-\frac{i}{2}(z-\bar z)\in \mathbb{R}.$
I was wondering if the following is true:
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2},~\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z}=\frac{1}{2},~\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}=-\frac{i}{2},~\frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar z}=\frac{i}{2}.
$$
It seems true, but I don't know the reason exactly. The transformation
$(z,\bar z) \to (x,y)$ is not familiar with me. It does not seem that the usual chain rule for multivariable functions can be applied.

Please let me know if you have any comment for my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The relations are true and they follow like in any change of variables since over the reals, $z, \bar z$ are independent variables

Comment: By definition, $${\partial\over \partial z} = {1\over 2} \left( {\partial\over \partial x}+ {1\over i}{\partial\over \partial y} \right),$$ and similarly with $\overline z$. Your equalities follow from how the 'usual' partials behave.

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your comment. I figured out how to prove it.

Comment: Great and happy to help!